# What does the phrase “source real products” mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the expression "source real products, mock up your space, and bring it to life with AR" in the following sentence:

[Morpholio Board lets you **source real products**, mock up your space, and bring it to life with AR.](https://apps.apple.com/us/story/morpholio-board/id1475021279)

For more context, here is another excerpt from the same text:

Have an eye for interior design? It’s easier than ever to realize your vision, from finding the perfect chairs to picking a wall color to complement them....Start by dragging product images onto your blank board. There are thousands in the app, everything from bath tiles to light fixtures to furniture by manufacturers like Knoll, Blu Dot, and Poliform, as well as retailers like Design Within Reach. You can also import your own images.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Morpholio Board is a piece of software that lets you create models of interior design projects. "Source real products" means that you can put items based on real products into the model. So a real chair made by company X might be available within the software for you to add to your model.

Comment: Here the verb “source” means to “to find or acquire the place where something is made, mined, stored, etc” - in other words, “find a supplier”. So, “source real products” here refers to the software’s ability to let you find real products (for presentation in your design) that are available in the real world and capable of being ordered from an actual supplier.